# Windows Live Contacts API Error on Getting E-Mail hashes - JavaScript

Tags: windows, api, contacts, msn, import-contacts

The following codes for the Window Live Contacts API to Get all email address from. Its works fine in login, log-out, and other authentications. I can collect all user information of logged in user with `Get Data` function call, but am getting email hashes of users, rest of the email hashes are blank. I have 10 email address in my contact book.

How do i get the email addresses of my contacts using this api?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='signUserIn();'>signUserIn</a> <br>
    <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='signUserOut()'>signUserOut</a><br>

    <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='loginStatus()'>Check User Status</a>

    <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='getData()'>Get Data</a>

    <script type="text/javascript" >

        WL.init({
            client_id: '0000000044444444',
            redirect_uri: 'http://domain.com/contact.php',
            response_type: "token",
            logging: true
        });

        var scopesArr = ['wl.signin', 'wl.basic', 'wl.emails'];

        function signUserIn() {
            WL.login({ scope: scopesArr });

        }

        function loginStatus() {
            WL.getLoginStatus(function(response) { 
            alert("response " + response );

            });
        }

        function getData() {
            alert( "getData");

            WL.api(
                {
                    path: "me/contacts",
                    method: "GET",
                    scope: scopesArr
                },
                    function (result) {

                        if (!result.error) {
                            var resultData = result.data;

                            var emailHashes = new Array;                    
                            for (i = 0; i < resultData.length; i++) {

                                for (j = 0; j < resultData[i].email_hashes.length; j++) {
                                    alert( "resultData " + resultData[i].email_hashes[j]);
                                    emailHashes[emailHashes.length] = resultData[i].email_hashes[j];
                                }
                            }
                            var resultText = "";
                            for (k = 0; k < emailHashes.length; k++) {
                                resultText += emailHashes[k] + "\r\n";                    
                            }

                           // document.getElementById("emailHashes").setAttribute("rows", emailHashes.length);
                            document.getElementById("lists").value = resultText;
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Error getting contacts: " + result.error.message);
                        }
            });

        }

        function signUserOut() {
            WL.logout();
        }

    </script>

    <textarea rows="10" cols="100" id="lists"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and I find the solution, all you need to do is add the following scope to your list of scopes you're requesting: "wl.contacts_emails"

```
WL.login({scopes: ["wl.contacts_emails"]});
```

After did that, I had to remove my application from my profile to reset all scope and add a second time my application. (But if you don't want to ask all people who alerady use your apps, I can just reset secret token to force user to add again your app).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not allow you to get your contacts emails via API. They only issue email hashes used to match emails on your end.

Sorry to break it to you, but you are out of luck.

I have spent 5 days now trying to get Hotmail contacts and I can't figure it out.

Comment: then how twitter is fetching email ids?

Comment: -1 This is not correct. The API will only show you hashes if you haven't requested the correct permissions, as @Thierry pointed out.